# DQL with many to many join

Tags: symfony, request, doctrine, dql

I try to make a DQL join with multiple join and the many to many one give me an error:
The SQL request :

```
SELECT * from products
JOIN producer
on products.producer = producer.id
JOIN distribution_producer
ON producer.id = distribution_producer.producer_id
WHERE distribution_producer.distribution_id = 1
```

Entity class Products:

```
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
     /**
     * @var \Producer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Producer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="producer", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $producer;
...
getter/setter
```

Entity class Producer:

```
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Producer::class, inversedBy="producers")
     */
    private $distributions;
...
getter/setter
```

Entity class Distribution :

```
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Producer::class, inversedBy="distributions")
     */
    private $producers;
...
getter/setter
```

My DQL Request in the products repository:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from('App\Entity\Products', 'p')
            ->join('p.producer', 'c')
            ->join('c.distributions', 'd')
            ->where('d.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', 1)
            ;
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $result;
```

The generated error :

*An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ty-terroir.producer_producer' doesn't exist*

The junction table for the M2M relation is called distribution_producer

I'm not sure about my DQL request

Comment: In producer entity, check distributions annotation, it says `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Producer::class, inversedBy="producers")` I guess it should be Distribution instead

Comment: Should the `targetEntity` of `$distributions` not be `Distribution` (instead of `Producer`)? Seems to be an unintended self-reference...

Answer (score -1):

You need to check this documentation https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional, but basically is missing an intermediate table, when you create an association many to many, doctrine is searching for an intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE users_phonenumbers (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    phonenumber_id INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX users_phonenumbers_phonenumber_id_uniq (phonenumber_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, phonenumber_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Phonenumber (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE users_phonenumbers ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
ALTER TABLE users_phonenumbers ADD FOREIGN KEY (phonenumber_id) REFERENCES Phonenumber(id);
```

Comment: i know that, and i have one like i told at the end: "The junction table for the M2M relation is called distribution_producer"
The thing is, doctrine doesn't call it.

In native SQL I'm able to call this table but not n DQL

Comment: You need to review the documentation. the documentation says:
`
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Producer::class, inversedBy="producers")
     * **@JoinTable(name="distribution_producer")**
     */
    private $distributions;
`
And also you need to review your mapping the class Producer, the attribute `distributions` is referring to himself instead of the Distribution entity.

You can check the result query with the methods

`$result = $qb->getQuery()->getDQL()` or `$result = $qb->getQuery()->getSQL()`